# Filtering the user-desired range from csv file

Tags: c, csv, file, struct, strtok

I have a csv file that data of earthquakes listed; i am asking to user which filter do you wanna apply (date,city or richter value )and then filter and print the results. I created a struct and using strtok(cause every string seperated with comma) but i got so much errors. How can i filter them, what is the logic of filtering? Please help me..:(

here is my code but as you can see i could not find what should i write at the end.

```
int sorgu(){

    FILE *fp;  //dosya pointer'ı

    fp = fopen("/Users/Desktop/earthquake.csv" , "r");

    int val=0;
    int min=0;
    int max=0;
    char *sp;  //string pointer
    char line[LINE];
    int filtre=0;
    struct earthquake;

    printf("***For which element do you want to filter?***\n");
    printf("PRESS 1 FOR DATE RANGE.\n");
    printf("PRESS 2 FOR CITY.\n");
    printf("PRESS 3 FOR DISTRICT.\n");
    printf("PRESS 4 FOR RICHTER VALUE.\n");
    scanf("%d" , &val);

    switch(filtre){

        case 1:
        printf("Enter the lower value for year.");
        scanf("%d" , &min);
        printf("Enter the upper value for year.");
        scanf("%d" , &max);

        while(fgets(line, LINE, fp) != NULL){

            sp=strtok(line, ",");  //string başından ilk virgülü görene kadar
            struct earthquake.id = atoi(sp);  //id değerini int değere çevirip earthquake.id'ye atar

            sp=strtok(NULL, ",");  //kaldığı virgülden itibaren diğer virgüle kadar
            strcpy(earthquake.date, sp);  //sp'yi earthquake.date'e kopyalar

           if(min<=date.upLimit && max>=date.topLimit){
               printf("Earthquakes in the range you specify: \n" , );
           }
        }



    }



    fclose(fp); 
}
```

[image: here is my csv file]

Comment: [Edit] and show the first 10 lines or so of `earthquake.csv` file as properly formatted text. Also show your code as [mcve]

Comment: "i got so much errors" Why do you not provide quote or detail of any of them?

Comment: If you get errors, why do you ignore the info which helps to find them? E.g. the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: What debugging did you do? Did you insert lots of outputs and compared the intermediate values of variables to what you expect? Did you use a debugger?